# how to create a text file in c# using visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, computer-vision, kinect

I have been trying to add a Write text file section to this project but i keep getting told that lots of things 'dont exist in the current context'. 
The text tile is meant to be created my documents showing 'First line,new line 1, new line 2'
This should work alongside the kinect sample.

[image]

I am sorry that i am very new to this and may be doing it completely wrong.

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="MainWindow.xaml.cs" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.HDFaceBasics
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
    using Microsoft.Kinect;
    using Microsoft.Kinect.Face;
    using System.IO;

    /// <summary>
    /// Main Window
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
        // Create a string array with the lines of text
        string text = "First line" + Environment.NewLine;

        // Set a variable to the My Documents path.
        string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        // Write the text to a new file named "WriteFile.txt".
        File.WriteAllText(mydocpath + @"\WriteFile.txt", text);

        // Create a string array with the additional lines of text
        string[] lines = { "New line 1", "New line 2" };

        // Append new lines of text to the file
        File.AppendAllLines(mydocpath + @"\WriteFile.txt", lines);



        /// <summary>
        /// Currently used KinectSensor
        /// </summary>
        private KinectSensor sensor = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Body frame source to get a BodyFrameReader
        /// </summary>
        private BodyFrameSource bodySource = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Body frame reader to get body frames
        /// </summary>
        private BodyFrameReader bodyReader = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// HighDefinitionFaceFrameSource to get a reader and a builder from.
        /// Also to set the currently tracked user id to get High Definition Face Frames of
        /// </summary>
        private HighDefinitionFaceFrameSource highDefinitionFaceFrameSource = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// HighDefinitionFaceFrameReader to read HighDefinitionFaceFrame to get FaceAlignment
        /// </summary>
        private HighDefinitionFaceFrameReader highDefinitionFaceFrameReader = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// FaceAlignment is the result of tracking a face, it has face animations location and orientation
        /// </summary>
        private FaceAlignment currentFaceAlignment = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// FaceModel is a result of capturing a face
        /// </summary>
        private FaceModel currentFaceModel = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// FaceModelBuilder is used to produce a FaceModel
        /// </summary>
        private FaceModelBuilder faceModelBuilder = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// The currently tracked body
        /// </summary>
        private Body currentTrackedBody = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// The currently tracked body
        /// </summary>
        private ulong currentTrackingId = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the current tracked user id
        /// </summary>
        private string currentBuilderStatus = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the current status text to display
        /// </summary>
        private string statusText = "Ready To Start Capture";

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// INotifyPropertyChangedPropertyChanged event to allow window controls to bind to changeable data
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the current status text to display
        /// </summary>
        public string StatusText
        {
            get
            {
                return this.statusText;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.statusText != value)
                {
                    this.statusText = value;

                    // notify any bound elements that the text has changed
                    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StatusText"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the current tracked user id
        /// </summary>
        private ulong CurrentTrackingId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.currentTrackingId;
            }

            set
            {
                this.currentTrackingId = value;

                this.StatusText = this.MakeStatusText();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the current Face Builder instructions to user
        /// </summary>
        private string CurrentBuilderStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return this.currentBuilderStatus;
            }

            set
            {
                this.currentBuilderStatus = value;

                this.StatusText = this.MakeStatusText();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when disposed of
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose based on whether or not managed or native resources should be freed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">Set to true to free both native and managed resources, false otherwise</param>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (this.currentFaceModel != null)
                {
                    this.currentFaceModel.Dispose();
                    this.currentFaceModel = null;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the length of a vector from origin
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="point">Point in space to find it's distance from origin</param>
        /// <returns>Distance from origin</returns>
        private static double VectorLength(CameraSpacePoint point)
        {
            var result = Math.Pow(point.X, 2) + Math.Pow(point.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(point.Z, 2);

            result = Math.Sqrt(result);

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the closest body from the sensor if any
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bodyFrame">A body frame</param>
        /// <returns>Closest body, null of none</returns>
        private static Body FindClosestBody(BodyFrame bodyFrame)
        {
            Body result = null;
            double closestBodyDistance = double.MaxValue;

            Body[] bodies = new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount];
            bodyFrame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(bodies);

            foreach (var body in bodies)
            {
                if (body.IsTracked)
                {
                    var currentLocation = body.Joints[JointType.SpineBase].Position;

                    var currentDistance = VectorLength(currentLocation);

                    if (result == null || currentDistance < closestBodyDistance)
                    {
                        result = body;
                        closestBodyDistance = currentDistance;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find if there is a body tracked with the given trackingId
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bodyFrame">A body frame</param>
        /// <param name="trackingId">The tracking Id</param>
        /// <returns>The body object, null of none</returns>
        private static Body FindBodyWithTrackingId(BodyFrame bodyFrame, ulong trackingId)
        {
            Body result = null;

            Body[] bodies = new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount];
            bodyFrame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(bodies);

            foreach (var body in bodies)
            {
                if (body.IsTracked)
                {
                    if (body.TrackingId == trackingId)
                    {
                        result = body;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current collection status
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="status">Status value</param>
        /// <returns>Status value as text</returns>
        private static string GetCollectionStatusText(FaceModelBuilderCollectionStatus status)
        {
            string res = string.Empty;

            if ((status & FaceModelBuilderCollectionStatus.FrontViewFramesNeeded) != 0)
            {
                res = "FrontViewFramesNeeded";
                return res;
            }

            if ((status & FaceModelBuilderCollectionStatus.LeftViewsNeeded) != 0)
            {
                res = "LeftViewsNeeded";
                return res;
            }

            if ((status & FaceModelBuilderCollectionStatus.RightViewsNeeded) != 0)
            {
                res = "RightViewsNeeded";
                return res;
            }

            if ((status & FaceModelBuilderCollectionStatus.TiltedUpViewsNeeded) != 0)
            {
                res = "TiltedUpViewsNeeded";
                return res;
            }

            if ((status & FaceModelBuilderCollectionStatus.Complete) != 0)
            {
                res = "Complete";
                return res;
            }

            if ((status & FaceModelBuilderCollectionStatus.MoreFramesNeeded) != 0)
            {
                res = "TiltedUpViewsNeeded";
                return res;
            }

            return res;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper function to format a status message
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Status text</returns>
        private string MakeStatusText()
        {
            string status = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Builder Status: {0}, Current Tracking ID: {1}", this.CurrentBuilderStatus, this.CurrentTrackingId);

            return status;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires when Window is Loaded
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.InitializeHDFace();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize Kinect object
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeHDFace()
        {
            this.CurrentBuilderStatus = "Ready To Start Capture";

            this.sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();
            this.bodySource = this.sensor.BodyFrameSource;
            this.bodyReader = this.bodySource.OpenReader();
            this.bodyReader.FrameArrived += this.BodyReader_FrameArrived;

            this.highDefinitionFaceFrameSource = new HighDefinitionFaceFrameSource(this.sensor);
            this.highDefinitionFaceFrameSource.TrackingIdLost += this.HdFaceSource_TrackingIdLost;

            this.highDefinitionFaceFrameReader = this.highDefinitionFaceFrameSource.OpenReader();
            this.highDefinitionFaceFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.HdFaceReader_FrameArrived;

            this.currentFaceModel = new FaceModel();
            this.currentFaceAlignment = new FaceAlignment();

            this.InitializeMesh();
            this.UpdateMesh();


            this.sensor.Open();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a 3D mesh to deform every frame
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeMesh()
        {
            var vertices = this.currentFaceModel.CalculateVerticesForAlignment(this.currentFaceAlignment);

            var triangleIndices = this.currentFaceModel.TriangleIndices;

            var indices = new Int32Collection(triangleIndices.Count);

            for (int i = 0; i < triangleIndices.Count; i += 3)
            {
                uint index01 = triangleIndices[i];
                uint index02 = triangleIndices[i + 1];
                uint index03 = triangleIndices[i + 2];

                indices.Add((int)index03);
                indices.Add((int)index02);
                indices.Add((int)index01);
            }

            this.theGeometry.TriangleIndices = indices;
            this.theGeometry.Normals = null;
            this.theGeometry.Positions = new Point3DCollection();
            this.theGeometry.TextureCoordinates = new PointCollection();

            foreach (var vert in vertices)
            {
                this.theGeometry.Positions.Add(new Point3D(vert.X, vert.Y, -vert.Z));
                this.theGeometry.TextureCoordinates.Add(new Point());
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends the new deformed mesh to be drawn
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateMesh()
        {
            var vertices = this.currentFaceModel.CalculateVerticesForAlignment(this.currentFaceAlignment);

            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
            {
                var vert = vertices[i];
                this.theGeometry.Positions[i] = new Point3D(vert.X, vert.Y, -vert.Z);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start a face capture on clicking the button
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void StartCapture_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.StartCapture();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This event fires when a BodyFrame is ready for consumption
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void BodyReader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.CheckOnBuilderStatus();

            var frameReference = e.FrameReference;
            using (var frame = frameReference.AcquireFrame())
            {
                if (frame == null)
                {
                    // We might miss the chance to acquire the frame, it will be null if it's missed
                    return;
                }

                if (this.currentTrackedBody != null)
                {
                    this.currentTrackedBody = FindBodyWithTrackingId(frame, this.CurrentTrackingId);

                    if (this.currentTrackedBody != null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                Body selectedBody = FindClosestBody(frame);

                if (selectedBody == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.currentTrackedBody = selectedBody;
                this.CurrentTrackingId = selectedBody.TrackingId;

                this.highDefinitionFaceFrameSource.TrackingId = this.CurrentTrackingId;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This event is fired when a tracking is lost for a body tracked by HDFace Tracker
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void HdFaceSource_TrackingIdLost(object sender, TrackingIdLostEventArgs e)
        {
            var lostTrackingID = e.TrackingId;

            if (this.CurrentTrackingId == lostTrackingID)
            {
                this.CurrentTrackingId = 0;
                this.currentTrackedBody = null;
                if (this.faceModelBuilder != null)
                {
                    this.faceModelBuilder.Dispose();
                    this.faceModelBuilder = null;
                }

                this.highDefinitionFaceFrameSource.TrackingId = 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This event is fired when a new HDFace frame is ready for consumption
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void HdFaceReader_FrameArrived(object sender, HighDefinitionFaceFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var frame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
            {
                // We might miss the chance to acquire the frame; it will be null if it's missed.
                // Also ignore this frame if face tracking failed.
                if (frame == null || !frame.IsFaceTracked)
                {
                    return;
                }

                frame.GetAndRefreshFaceAlignmentResult(this.currentFaceAlignment);
                this.UpdateMesh();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start a face capture operation
        /// </summary>
        private void StartCapture()
        {
            this.StopFaceCapture();

            this.faceModelBuilder = null;

            this.faceModelBuilder = this.highDefinitionFaceFrameSource.OpenModelBuilder(FaceModelBuilderAttributes.None);

            this.faceModelBuilder.BeginFaceDataCollection();

            this.faceModelBuilder.CollectionCompleted += this.HdFaceBuilder_CollectionCompleted;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cancel the current face capture operation
        /// </summary>
        private void StopFaceCapture()
        {
            if (this.faceModelBuilder != null)
            {
                this.faceModelBuilder.Dispose();
                this.faceModelBuilder = null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This event fires when the face capture operation is completed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void HdFaceBuilder_CollectionCompleted(object sender, FaceModelBuilderCollectionCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var modelData = e.ModelData;

            this.currentFaceModel = modelData.ProduceFaceModel();

            this.faceModelBuilder.Dispose();
            this.faceModelBuilder = null;

            this.CurrentBuilderStatus = "Capture Complete";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check the face model builder status
        /// </summary>
        private void CheckOnBuilderStatus()
        {
            if (this.faceModelBuilder == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            string newStatus = string.Empty;

            var captureStatus = this.faceModelBuilder.CaptureStatus;
            newStatus += captureStatus.ToString();

            var collectionStatus = this.faceModelBuilder.CollectionStatus;

            newStatus += ", " + GetCollectionStatusText(collectionStatus);

            this.CurrentBuilderStatus = newStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you expect `File.WriteAllText(mydocpath + @"\WriteFile.txt", text);` to happen? It is not inside any function.

Comment: You should check some hello world example first.

Comment: `using System.IO;` is required at first of your file. or write namespace explicitly `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a method that you can call that will allow you to create as well as append to the file

```
private static void WriteAndOrAppendText(string path, string strText)
{
    using (StreamWriter fileStream = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        fileStream.WriteLine(strText);
        fileStream.Flush();
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}

// Set a variable to the My Documents path.
string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

// Write the text to a new file named "WriteFile.txt".
WriteAndOrAppendText(mydocpath + @"\WriteFile.txt", text);

string[] lines = { "New line 1", "New line 2" };
WriteAndOrAppendText(mydocpath , string.Join(",", lines.ToArray()));
```